# SWR Data passed as prop to child component creates infinite fetch loop

Tags: reactjs, swr

In SWR, once I receive a fetch result, I want to pass it to a child component as a prop.
Hook defined as:

```
const fetcher = url => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data);

export default function useTeleworkInfoSWR() {

    const { data, error } = useSWR('/teleworkInfo', fetcher);

    return {
        teleworkInfo: data,
        teleworkInfoIsLoading: !error && !data,
        teleworkInfoError: error
    }

}
```

Used in the Home component as follows:

```
const {teleworkInfo, teleworkInfoIsLoading, teleworkInfoError} = useTeleworkInfoSWR();

...
return (<>
     ...
     <SomeComponent abc={teleworkInfo} />    
</>);
```

This is creating an infinite loop of some kind, and SWR is always busy. Do I need to call SWR separately in that child component rather than pass it as a prop?

Comment: Doesn't SWR need a 'revalidate' parameter?

Comment: I just want a reusable data fetch hook that I can use wherever needed. I don't want to auto-refresh by itself.